# Working out point location relative to other point when rotated - C# XNA

Tags: c#, math, xna, geometry, rotation

I have a small rectangle, with a point at the center. I also have another point, just outside of the rectangle, 10 pixels to the left of the rectangle's center point when the rectangle is sitting vertically, not rotated. How would i go about keeping this outside point in the same place relative to the rectangle when the rectangle is rotated about its center?

thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question - since you are rotating about the center, the center-point won't move, so just keep the exterior point in exactly the same place...

Comment: Sorry; bad wording on my part - i essentially just meant to keep the exterior point in the same place relative to the rotation of the rectangle

Comment: So then rotate the point by the same amount, using the same center of rotation...

Comment: The rectangle isn't rotated that way, its rotation is simply set and then it is drawn with said rotation by a SpriteBatch

Comment: Of course it works like that - even if the framework didn't support rotating vectors (which it does - see my answer below), it would be a simple matter to calculate the sin/cos of the angle.  Perhaps you should brush up on your trig and vector-math - you'll need to use them both *a lot* to write a game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to rotate one point around another point in XNA:

```
public Vector2 RotatePoint(Vector2 pointToRotate, Vector2 centerOfRotation, float angleOfRotation)
{
    Matrix rotationMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(angleOfRotation);
    return Vector2.Transform(pointToRotate - centerOfRotation, rotationMatrix);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Start the "point" at the center point of your rectangle, then translate it out to where you want it, and then rotate it from there.